# How do I enable innodb on Workbench 6.0?

Tags: innodb, mysql-workbench

I searched a lot online, but I can not yet find how to enable innodb in workbench 6.0. Some search results mentioned changing the my.ini file, but I can not find this file.

[image]

Comment: You need to enable the engine on the server, not the client. If your server is running Linux then you need to modify `/etc/my.cnf`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question within the scope defined in the [help]

Comment: Your previous comment helped me realize where was located the my.cnf file and so reach a solution to my question. I think this topic can be useful and help other people who are programming with MySQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** my.cnf (located on the server side - e.g. on Windows localhost, if you are working with WAMP: C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf) has to be changed:

Putting a # sign before 'skip-innodb' disables this command. Then the restart of mysql will enable InnoDB engine.